# statistical discrimination VS taste based discrimination

Tags: preferences, statistics, discrimination

Given the progress in the literature on economics of discrimination. What is the reason for still believing in the dichotomy taste-based VS statistical discrimination. I think the first theory is just a specific case of statistical discrimination, where information on discriminated workers' productivity is weighted by the discrimination coefficient (which basically is just a scaling factor). Any attempt to disentangle the two types of discrimination is pointless. Or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find below two good and recent surveys on the literature on economics of discrimination and they all point out a clear difference between taste-based and statistical discrimination. We can imagine a situation where the employer's information about workers' productivity is perfect, such that there is no statistical discrimination, and still observe a racial wage discrimination for example because the employer has a taste for discrimination. Knowing the source of discrimination seems crucial to fight against discrimination and its consequences.

Charles, K. K., and J. Guryan (2011): “Studying Discrimination: Fundamental
Challenges and Recent Progress,” Annual Review of Economics,
3(1), 479–511.

Lang, K., and J.-Y. K. Lehmann (2012): “Racial Discrimination in the
Labor Market: Theory and Empirics,” Journal of Economic Literature,
50(4), 959–1006.

Comment: I absolutely agree that in countries like the US, where there is a legal distinction between the two theories, the disentanglement is crucial. I am thinking just about whether it is possible to build a single model of discrimination that incorporates both the theories (and their evolution)